# ¿Cómo evitar que inyecten código js mediante una extensión web a mi página web?

Tags: javascript, html5, aplicación-web

La pregunta va relacionada a cómo controlar aquellas extensiones web que inyectan código **javascript** a una página web en concreto... Ejm...

Yo tengo una web creada en **Html5**, a esta página(la mía) yo le he añadido un pequeño juego de monedas para hacerla más interactiva, lo que pasa es que algunos  usuarios se han creado una extensión para google chrome que inyecta código js en mi web y de esa forma hacen trampa en dicho juego por así decirlo....

¿Alguna respuesta de orientación?, se les agradece mucho.

Comment: Sin ver código, lo único que te puedo decir es que lleves todo lo "sensible" en el servidor, osea, los calculos para acertar, el incrementar decrementar monedas, y que el cliente sea un terminal tonto, solo pinte lo que el servidor le diga. De este modo, evitas que puedan, en primer lugar como son las funciones que calculan el tiro,.etc. y que con js no puedan hacer gran cosa. También te recomendaría cambiar el calculo que tengas ahora para acertar, para evitar que el plugin que hayan echo siga funcionando

Comment: Muchisimasss gracias, lo tendré muy en cuenta, a ver si con el método Ajax pueda solucionarlo... De nuevo gracias por la respuesta :,D

Comment: Si lo haces con ajax estarás en una situación similar, el código js esta en el cliente, si es alguien que sabe un poco verá como haces la petición ajax al servidor y se puede "replicar" intentando aprovechar fallos. Sinceramente creo que es mejor que descartes lógica importante en js.

Comment: Disculpa me equivoque no quise decir metodo Ajax, estaba pensando en otro lio aparte... Lo que quise decir es que espero solucionarlo usando un framework como NodeJs... ¿Crees que es una buena idea ?

Comment: Si, podría ser una buena opción.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por contestar... Veré que puedo hacer al respecto.. Saludos .

Comment: Justamente y de manera muy random un compañero del trabajo me ha mostrado algo, que te vendría al pelo. No he indagado mucho pero es la ****. Se llama "Content Security Policy (CSP)" y sirve para restringir mediante normativas en las cabeceras, la ejecución de js, css, iframes, y otros. De modo que puedes estableces de donde quieres que si se pueda ejecutar el javascript y de donde no. Por lo que evitas que puedan hacer cualquier scripting injection o cosas por el estilo(tiene limitaciones o pegas) Echale un ojo. (en caniuse puedes ver que esta aceptado casi por todos los navegadores)

Comment: Cielos, no lo había pensado, ahora  mismo le echo un ojo... Y te confirmo como me va. Muchas gracias de nuevo me haces de mucha ayuda

Comment: Lo estoy viendo ahora y parece ser la solución que he estado buscando

Comment: Me alegro que te sea de ayuda. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código JS se ejecuta en el navegador del cliente, por lo que poco o nada se puede hacer. La única opción que tienes es que cada X tiempo mediante JavaScript (Ajax o WebSockets) mandes algo al servidor y el servidor lleve un control de los progresos de dicho usuario.

En el caso que comentas de un algoritmo de tiro pongamos de ejemplo como valores internos: velocidad del viento, dirección del viento y situación del objetivo. El usuario realmente tiene dos variables: ángulo y fuerza.

Para evitar tener tódo tu código del cálculo expuesto en la parte del cliente mediante JavaScript te recomendaría que el servidor calculase los valores internos y los almacenase en una base de datos, fichero o similar asignándo un código a los mismos, por ejemplo el ID:27. El servidor devolvería vía Ajax al cliente JavaScript este ID además de una imagen en la que aparezca una flecha para la dirección del viento, una barra para la fuerza, y el punto de objetivo. Todo ello en una imagen, por lo que así no se le da al cliente ninguna pista de valores numéricos para calcular nada.

Una vez el cliente "dispare" se envíar vía Ajax al servidor el ID interno de los parámetros que se han calculado para esa pantalla (ID:27) además de los parámetros de usuario de fuerza y ángulo.

En el servidor se recuperaría mediante el ID:27 los parámetros internos, se tomarían los parámetros de usuario y se calcularía si acierta o no. El servidor devolvería un 0=fallo, o un 1=ok para hacer alguna animación en el cliente (al gusto) y marcaría en la base de datos el ID:27 como utilizado.

De esta manera ni expones tu código de tiro, ni le das pistas matemáticas al usuario, ya que estaría trabajando con una imagen sin datos numéricos.

Comment: El juego consiste en lanzar una moneda por un agujero pero tiene su dificultad, ya que para hacer un tiro preciso se tiene que tener en cuenta el angulo de lanzamiento de la moneda, el viento(eso puede afectar la trayectoria de la moneda)  la distancia y la fuerza... Si aciertas ganas puntos... Ahora, los usuarios para hacer trampa han creado una extensión para chrome que inyecta código js a mi pagina web  y así obtener las medidas precisas o sea la extensión   le marca la fuerza precisa de lanzamiento con el cual hacen un tiro preciso.

Comment: Todo eso si lo hacen en la parte cliente no hay solución sencilla. En tu caso, te sugeriría q esos parámetros q utiliza la función JS q utilizan ellos (viento, distancia y demás), q son parámetros q tu le ofreces al usuario para q calcule como tiene q tirar, los generara el servidor aleatoriamente y q se los mostrases al cliente en formato gráfico con una barra o similar de forma q ya no tendrán una base matemática q tomar para sus cálculos. Obviamente al generar automáticamente esos datos tendrás q ofrecer un código al JS y luego procesar ese código+angulo+fuerza para calcular el éxito o no.

Comment: Y ahí esta el problema que cuando lo añado al js el algoritmo de tiro  queda expuesto del lado del cliente, pero como dices tu, debo hacerlo del lado del servidor, pero, peroo, encontre otro post en esta pagina que me hizo notar algo, por ejm, pongo mi javascript (donde esta mi algoritmo de tiro) del lado del servidor con nodejs luego al momento de intercambiar datos json entre servidor y el cliente  los parámetros de tiro de nuevo quedaran expuestos del lado del cliente al refrescar la pagina.

Comment: Provocando que el atacante obtenga mi javascript y lo meta en su extensión web para luego modificarla e inyectármela de nuevo  como le sucedió a esta chica ...¿o me equivoco ?https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90915/puedo-encriptar-o-ofuscar-el-javascript-de-las-conexiones-de-tipo-xhr-que-est%C3%A1n/90925#90925

Comment: Edito mi respuesta que así puedo escribir más que en un comentario.

Comment: Leyendo nuevamente, tu primera respuesta, ya le encuentro el punto y si tiene mucha lógica lo que dices. Y es la mejor respuesta a mi problema.